# Django Rest Framework request unauthorized on all but one address

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access django hosted at 192.168.x.x:8000 on a React frontend server on port 5002, when attempting to access the frontend with localhost, 127.0.0.1 or ip's outside of the home network, it gives following result in console:

```
Unauthorized: /api/any_endpoint
HTTP POST /api/any_endpoint 401 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:12345]
```

However when accessing trough 192.168.x.x:5002, it just works. the /admin/ endpoint seems to work no matter the ip address (ip_address:8000), so it's either django-rest-framework or React that is causing this issue. I have no idea where to start debugging this, so any comment on what I should check would be appreciated

Comment: are you using token auth?

Comment: I've narrowed it down, django will only allow connections from the same address as the backend that it's coming from, also no I am not using any token auth for these api endpoints as far as I'm aware of